# Meteor.js: Understanding sort parameters within a find{} method

Tags: meteor

I am doing exercises in the book "Getting Started With Meteor.js Javascript Framework" and 
there is a section where a template called categories is created, then a {#each} loop thumbs through a collection.This is done with the intent of printing the results to the screen. This works and the code is below.

```
<template name ="categories">

    <div class ="title">my stuff</div>

    <div id='categories'>
        {{#each lists}}

        <div id="category">

            {{Category}}

        </div>

        {{/each}}
    </div>

</template>
```

**My question is this:**

In the code below the sort parameter doesn't seem to do anything. I am curious what it is supposed to be doing. I understand that theoretically it's suppose to "sort", but when I play with the parameters nothing changes. I looked it up in the meteor documentation and I couldn't figure it out. I am trying to modify the code so that it so that it sorts in a different order. This way I can see results and get a real understanding of how **{sort:**  works. I tried modifying the **{sort: {Category: 1}})** to **{sort: {Category: -1}})** as well as **{sort: {Category: 2}})** and it's always the same result.

```
  Template.categories.lists = function() {
    return lists.find({}, {sort: {Category: 1}});  // Works

  /* return lists.find({}); */                     // Works just the same

  }
```

The Collections are as follows:

```
lists.insert({Category:"DVDs", items: [{Name:"Mission Impossible" ,Owner:"me",LentTo:"Alice"}]});

lists.insert({Category:"Tools", items: [{Name:"Linear Compression Wrench",Owner:"me",LentTo: "STEVE"}]});
```

Answer (score 3):

In your code, you can attempt to change the argument of the sort to be an array instead of an object, like this:
`sort: [["Category","asc"],["another argument","desc"],[...]]`
so the code :

```
 Template.categories.lists = function() {
    return lists.find({}, {
        sort: [
            ["Category", "asc"],
            ["another argument", "desc"],
            [...]
        ]
    }); 
    // return lists.find({}); // Works just the same
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding that is because default is to sort by natural order. More info can be found at this [link](http://docs.meteor.com/#find)

Comment: I read that prior to posting and it's still confusing. When I replace it with {skip: {Category: 1}}); I don't see a change. I guess the real question is "How to use the Selector Option in the find method".

Comment: as i mentioned earlier, If no option is given, it sorts in nautral order i.e ascending order. using (sort:{catagory:1}} also sorts the results in ascending order. Hence the similar results.

Comment: I am trying to change it so that it sorts in a different order.This way I can see results and get a real understanding of how it works.

Comment: you can try by doing a sort on  {sort: {Category: -1}} with little more random data which is not in sorted order. I hope you have more than 10-20 category's to test with.

Comment: I have 5 categories and doing -1 doesn't create any change.

Comment: can u add them to your problem description like you added 2 above ?